# SQL Calculate a sum by replacement

Tags: sql

So I have this table of `badges` (kinda' like STO has)

```
| user_id |  grade  |
---------------------
|  1      |  bronze |
|  1      |  silver |
|  2      |  bronze |
|  1      |  gold   |
|  1      |  bronze |
|  3      |  gold   | 
|  1      |  gold   |
```

And I want to calculate the total sum of badge-points for user `id 1`. 
Every `bronze` badge should be equal to `5`, every `silver` - `50`, `gold` - `200`.

So in the end I need to get 460 for this sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a specific user_id:

```
select
  sum(case grade
    when 'bronze' then 5
    when 'silver' then 50
    when 'gold' then 200
    end
   )
from tablename
where user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty basic conditional aggregation:

```
sum (case when grade = 'bronze' then 5
when grade = 'silver' then 50
when grade = 'gold' then 200
else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use `case` and `sum()`:

```
select user_id,
       sum(case when grade = 'bronze' then 5
                when grade = 'silver' then 50
                when grade = 'gold' then 200
           end)
from t
group by user_id;
```

Comment: in some dialects (like postgres, oracle, ...) you may use the shorter `case` form: `case grade when 'bronze' then 5 when 'silver' then 50 when 'gold' 200 else <default value> end`

Comment: @BrunoZamengo . . . That would be true in all databases.  The SQL standard has both types of `case` expression and I'm not aware of any database that doesn't support the simple `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Put those badge values into a another table and join to it. Or at least use a table expression.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(BadgeVal) AS Total
  FROM T
  INNER JOIN 
    (VALUES ('bronze',5)
           ,('silver',50)
           ,('gold',200)) 
    AS BadgeValues(grade, BadgeVal)
   ON T.grade = BadgeValues.grade
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY user_id;
```

Note that this syntax works with SQL Server, does not work with MySQL to my knowledge, and I have no idea about Oracle or Postgres or any other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

## Here you go using decode function :

`SELECT SUM(t.grade_point) 
 FROM (SELECT id,grade,decode(grade,'bronze',5,'silver',50,'gold',200) AS grade_point
       FROM badges where id =1) t;`

Comment: Note that `DECODE` is only a built-in function in Oracle, although it's pretty easy to code up in any other DBMS as a UDF.